# How to concat multiple video files which have different stream order with FFmpeg?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, concatenation

I have 3 video files with following info:

```
Input #0, mpegts, from '01.ts':
  Duration: 00:00:06.08, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 931 kb/s
  Program 1
    Stream #0:0[0x101]: Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 65 kb/s
    Stream #0:1[0x102]: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(progressive), 852x480 [SAR 640:639 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc


Input #0, mpegts, from '02.ts':
  Duration: 00:00:06.06, start: 6.016000, bitrate: 872 kb/s
    Stream #0:0[0x102]: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(progressive), 852x480 [SAR 640:639 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x101]: Audio: aac (LC), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 66 kb/s


Input #0, mpegts, from '03.ts':
  Duration: 00:00:06.07, start: 12.010667, bitrate: 822 kb/s
    Stream #0:0[0x102]: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(progressive), 852x480 [SAR 640:639 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x101]: Audio: aac (LC), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 69 kb/s
```

Most of them are the same, but somehow 01.ts has different stream order with the other two. My question is, how to concat them? I've tried to put them in a txt file and concat:

```
-f concat -safe 0 -i video_file.txt -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc output.mp4
```

But it's not working. Error message is:

```
Error parsing ADTS frame header!
Error applying bitstream filters to an output packet for stream #0:1.
```

And what if I have hundreds of video files that may have diffrent stream order like this?

**EDIT**

[aergistal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54485169/927622) is correct, but I have another problem: in another collection of videos, the stream ids are different, as following:

```
Input #0, mpegts, from 'another1.ts':
  Duration: 00:00:08.04, start: 17.401333, bitrate: 284 kb/s
  Program 1
    Metadata:
      service_name    : Service01
      service_provider: FFmpeg
    Stream #0:0[0x100]: Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(progressive), 352x288 [SAR 16:11 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x101]: Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 124 kb/s


Input #0, mpegts, from 'another2.ts':
  Duration: 00:00:08.04, start: 33.401333, bitrate: 300 kb/s
  Program 1
    Metadata:
      service_name    : Service01
      service_provider: FFmpeg
    Stream #0:0[0x100]: Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(progressive), 352x288 [SAR 16:11 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x101]: Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 145 kb/s
```

Is there a way to set the `exact_stream_id` automatically instead of check it everytime?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [concat demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat-1) has an `exact_stream_id` which might help. Use the PIDs and the following format for your concat list (`video_file.txt`):

```
file 01.ts
stream
exact_stream_id 0x102
stream
exact_stream_id 0x101

file 02.ts
stream
exact_stream_id 0x102
stream
exact_stream_id 0x101

file 03.ts
stream
exact_stream_id 0x102
stream
exact_stream_id 0x101
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. But I got another problem about different stream ids. I've added the detail in the question editing section, Could you help me?

Comment: You can use [ffprobe](https://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html) to print information about the streams, including the IDs: `ffprobe -show_streams` or `ffprobe -show_entries stream=id`. It can also output CSV, JSON etc. Check out the documentation.